# Laravel login redirect

Tags: laravel, authentication

I'm trying to redirect the login to another page.

Right now it's redirecting to '/' even though in the login controller it says '/welcome'.
(Using default authentication of laravel).

It looks like it completely ignores the login controller.

**LoginController.php**

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers; 

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/welcome'; 

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }
}
```

As it seems like it's completely ignoring the login controller, i'm confused on how it's even possible to login.

Comment: Do you mean that it's redirecting to `/` **after** logging in successfully?

Comment: Yep, thats what i mean, it's strange as it says to redirect to /welcome

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what version of Laravel you are using, this solution may work for you.

Within the App\Http\Middleware section take a look at the file RedirectIfAuthenticated.

You will find a handle() method which redirects the user once authed.

Update that redirect and you should be good to go.

Comment: I've also looked into this.


`<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class RedirectIfAuthenticated
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @param  string|null  $guard
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
            return redirect('/home');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
`

Comment: What was the outcome after updaing the url here? You may want to try clear any cache using some of the Artisan features.

Comment: Changing the redirect in that file didn't actually change the redirect

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: We're using laravel 5.4

Comment: The files are on a server, how do i run the php artisan route:clear on a server? I'm new to laravel.

Comment: If you have ssh access to your server you should be able to cd into the website directory and run that command. If you update your files via ftp, it maybe with checking if all of the files are updated correctly.

Comment: Yeah i thought so.. I'm using FTP. I've checked if they're updated multiple times :/

Comment: Do you have a dev version on the website? Are you facing the same problems on the local website?

Comment: Nope, the website is basically both.

Comment: I'm stuck now. I need to get this redirect to work, as i need to make another view appear..

Comment: Is this the same problem on your local dev version?

Answer (score 0):

You need to look in `app/Http/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php` to where its redirecting a successful request.

Comment: Ok, sorry about that. Are you certain that the user is logged in? Try doing a `dd(auth()->user())` on the page you get redirected to after you think you're logged in.

Comment: Yes, i'm certain the user is logged in. We can use auth()-user()

Comment: I'm using default Laravel 5.4 authentication

Comment: You may have already done this, but are you sure that you set `protected $redirectTo = '/home';` in your authcontroller ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

Issue was that the

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
   return redirect('/auth');
}
```

was empty before...